# Meaning of 'didn't dare'

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> **Mr. Dursley wondered whether he dared tell her he'd heard the name
>   "Potter." He decided he didn't dare.** Instead he said, as casually as
>   he could, "Their son -- he'd be about Dudley's age now, wouldn't he?"

What is the exact meaning of 'He decided, he didn't dare'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first sentence, Mr. Dursley is thinking and trying to decide whether he should or should not (in other words, if he will dare or will not dare to) tell her something. And after thinking about it, he decided that he shouldn't tell her that. That's what this `He decided he didn't dare` means: he decided not to tell her.